# How to get code coverage report for android instrumentation tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, code-coverage, android-instrumentation

How do I find the code coverage for instrumentation test case, the run tests with code coverage button is disabled.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Before that you need to enable Coverage in gradle file at app level .

```
 buildTypes {
        debug
                {
                    testCoverageEnabled = true
                }
}
```

Once done you can  run below command in Terminal

```
gradlew createDebugCoverageReport
```

You can check it at below path

```
YoutProjectName\app\build\reports\coverage\debug
```

and check index.html file in your browser.